# How do you setup admin media in Webfaction for Django?

Tags: django

I have my django setup. Now i just need to get the admin site to be correct. Currently there is no css asigned to it, so i guese my admin media urls etc in settings file is not correct?

Thanks

Comment: Well, why don't you post those settings? Also, your domain layout, your static apps, your urlconf, and those other things.

Answer (score 3):

Have you read through their [docs](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django.html#serving-admin-media)? Or is there something in there that wasn't working?

This seems more like a question to ask on their [forum](http://forum.webfaction.com/). Their tech people usually respond pretty quickly.

Comment: Make sure you read about setting up static files, also. See http://docs.webfaction.com/software/static.html#serving-static-media

Answer (score 0):

you need to issue

```
pythonX.Y manage.py collectstatic
```

where X.Y is the version of your application's python. this will copy admin media inside your static directory.